# Google Tag Manager js library sometimes loading sometimes not

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, magento2, google-tag-manager

We are using Magento 2 CMS and we add a proper script like this -

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XYZ');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

But it is loading sometimes and sometimes not.

When we checked in the view page source then found that the **`j.src`** value shows nothing.

Does anyone know how to resolve this or How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't check j.src. You're outside of that function.

Instead, check the script in DOM and its fetching in Network. Or even just it's JS presence via the dataLayer changes it makes when it loads.

Comment: I checked in the Network there is also not showing

Comment: Well then check dom, see if the script load function was added and check your JS console for errors.

Comment: I checked in DOM this was not showing and there is no console error.

Comment: And the script that you add is not in DOM either? Then you're adding it in a wrong place/wrong html template. Find your all your header templates if you have more than one and add it there.

Comment: script is present in DOM, only j.src=' '; is showing empty,in my localhost it is working fine always loading but in the live domain it is not working properly,it loading sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: it looks like you have a race condition. Looks like a different script trying to suppress others. When GTM loads before it, it works fine. If it loads before GTM, it suppresses it. Cookie autoblockers do something very similar to this. They also often want to load syncly exactly because they want to be in a good position to block others. One Trust is a prime example, though instead of removing the source, it changes text/javascript to text/plain. Do you use any third party cookie consent management system like that?

Comment: Yes i am using third-party cookie in Magento 2 of Amasty extension

Comment: try disabling it on lowers. See if that fixes the GTM issues. If it does, then maybe whitelist GTM and its resources.

Comment: when accept cookies it is working fine,but before accepting cookies it is not working

Comment: well there we go, we now have our reason. Your cookie blocking solution interferes with GTM.